# Видео не воспроизводится с первого раза при наведении

Tags: jquery, видео, webbrowser

Есть каталог с видео фонами, при наведении на видео оно должно проигрываться, но иногда в браузерах (в частности opera) выводиться ошибка.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

```js
$('body').on("mouseover", ".services__item", function(){
  var videoBlock = $(this).find('.video'),
   video = videoBlock.get(0);

  if(videoBlock.length){
   video.play();
   videoBlock.css( "background-color", "black" );
  }
 });
 $('body').on("mouseleave", ".services__item", function(){
  var videoBlock = $(this).find('.video'),
   video = videoBlock.get(0);
  if(videoBlock.length){
   video.pause();
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services__item">
    <div class="services__media-wrp">
      <div class="services__media">
        <video class="video"loop>
          <source src="https://upread.ru/video/art144-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение

Попробуй проверять состояние проигрывания видео следующим образом, данная проверка подходит для любых типов медиа-файлов:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, "playing", {
  get: function get() {
    return !!(
      this.currentTime > 0 &&
      !this.paused &&
      !this.ended &&
      this.readyState > 2
    );
  }
});
```

То есть, если видео не проигрывается, то ты можешь это проверить следующим образом:

```
let videoBlock = $(this).find(".video");
if (!videoBlock.playing) {
  video.play();
  console.log('видео можно воспроизвести!')
}
```

### Пример

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, "playing", {
  get: function get() {
    return !!(
      this.currentTime > 0 &&
      !this.paused &&
      !this.ended &&
      this.readyState > 2
    );
  }
});

$("body").on("mouseover", ".services__item", function() {
  var videoBlock = $(this).find(".video"),
    video = videoBlock.get(0);

  if (!videoBlock.playing) {
    video.play();
    videoBlock.css("background-color", "black");
  }
});
$("body").on("mouseleave", ".services__item", function() {
  var videoBlock = $(this).find(".video"),
    video = videoBlock.get(0);
    video.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services__item">
    <div class="services__media-wrp">
      <div class="services__media">
        <video class="video"loop>
          <source src="https://upread.ru/video/art144-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Данная проблема возникает, потому что `play()` и `pause()` в каком-то смысле соревнуются, и вам необходимо четко определять когда видео не воспроизведено.

### Решение с `muted`

Вы так же можете использовать `muted` для `video`:

```
<video ... muted="muted"></video>
```

Но это не лучшее решение, потому что звук будет выключен, а если у вас видео или аудио со звуком, вам понадобиться совершать лишние действия для активации звука.

Comment: вроде бы заработало, muted мне и нужно, виде там просто как анимация фоновая

Comment: @Karalahti пожалуйста, пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошибку читали в консоле? Там же написано, что воспроизведение не удалось, потому что пользователь НЕ взаимодействовал с документом. Это политика автовоспроизведения.

Т.е. он считает, что раз ничего не делалось (не было клика) в DOM то это автовоспроизведения.

Для примера сделайте клик в любой части DOM потом наведите на видео. Будет работать.

Как вариант, может отключить звук по умолчанию

```
<video class="video" loop  muted="muted">
    <source src="https://upread.ru/video/art144-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```